# Chinese Characters corrupted when using Protractor sendKeys method

Tags: unicode, internationalization, protractor, globalization

Are there any known issues with using Protractor to enter SMP characters?
When I use the sendKeys() method, the result is two corrupted entries.
For example, when attempting to enter '' via the sendKeys('') the result in the UI is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQB3f.png).

And if I print out the sendKeys(''.length), the result is 2.  It seems like the character is being interpretted as two individual characters.
Is this a known issue with Protractor?

Much thanks in advance,
M

Comment: To note, the issue with the two characters has to do with `.length` counting the 16-bit code points, rather than "characters". `` is actually represented as two code points. If you try `console.log("".codePointAt(0), "".codePointAt(1))`, you'll get `131072 56320` I'm not familiar enough with internationalization to give a decent answer, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction. http://developer.teradata.com/blog/jasonstrimpel/2011/11/javascript-string-length-and-internationalizing-web-applications

Comment: Depending on exactly what your usecase is, you might be able to use URI Encoding instead. `encodeURIComponent("");` This will return `%F0%A0%80%80`, which will properly represent the character on Google. People will be able to provide more help if you provide your code and your particular use case.